# AJAX call in node/express doesn't seem to return data

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, express

I'm trying to implement AJAX in my node/express app for the first time, and I'm confused as to what's happening with my code.  I want to take a couple of inputs from a form and then run a calculation that shows the result on the same page.

my router.js:

```
router.get('/ajax', verified, function(req, res){
    res.render('ajax');
});

router.post('/ajax', verified, function(req, res) {
    if(req.xhr || req.accepts('json,html')==='json'){
        res.send({success: true});
    } else {
        res.redirect(303, '/ajax');
    }
});
```

part of my html:

```
<form action ="/ajax" class="form-horizontal pesoForm" method="POST" role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="#" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Model Type</label>
    <div id="porton-search" class="col-sm-6">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search for porton" name="portonModel">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="#" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Alto Libre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#" placeholder="Alto" name="alto">
        <div class="input-group-addon">cm</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="#" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Ancho Libre</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="#" placeholder="Ancho" name="ancho">
        <div class="input-group-addon">cm</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Calculate</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="resultContainer col-sm-12"></div>
```

My jquery ajax script at the bottom:

```
<script>
    $('document').ready(function(){
      $('form').on('submit', function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var action = $(this).attr('action');

          $.ajax({
            url: action,
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);

              if(data.success){
                $('.resultContainer').html('<p>It worked</p>');
              }  else {
                $('.resultContainer').html('<p>Oops, there was a problem</p>');
              }
            },
            error: function(){
              $('.resultContainer').html('Oops we have a problem');
            }
          });
      });
    });
</script>
```

When i run this on my local server, I get the object {success: true} returned in the console and the html 'It worked'.

However, *I'm not sure how to get my form data*.  Console.log(data) just seems to return {success:true}.

Note that I do have bodyParser middleware.

Comment: send data in this call `res.json({success: true, data:'somedata'});`

Comment: thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery ajax call is only going to get what you returned from express. So in this case all you returned is `{success: true}`. In express, you can access the post variables via `req.body.alto`. In express you can do whatever calculation you want and return an object that represents the results of that calculation, instead of just success being true.

On a side note, I believe you'll want to use `res.json()` to send back JSON data. `res.send` will send back string data, which jQuery will correct for you, but it's bad practice for many reasons I wont get into now

Comment: thanks, i've got my calculation w/ ajax working now!